# How do I get a nullable int[] with dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, dapper

If I want to get a bunch of rows containing a single column of `int`, using Dapper, and it's possible for this result set to be empty. What's the best way to use Dapper to query this data?

For Example, if I have the following method that returns what I want:

```
public void int[] GetInts()
{

    conn.Query<int?>("select 123 where 1=1")
        .Where(x=> x.HasValue)
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .ToArray();
}
```

If I change the line to this:

```
conn.Query<int>("select 123 where 1=0").ToArray();
```

I get a casting error when there are no results.

The Stack Trace is below and the exception is just an object reference not set to instance of an object when casting `(T)next`:

```
at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryInternal>d__13`1.MoveNext() in .\SqlMapper.cs:line 611
 at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)   
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in .\SqlMapper.cs:line 539
```

Comment: What's the exception? Stacktrace?

Comment: Neither example is compilable code.  Can you please take care to ensure both are exactly what you've tried?   (`x => v.Value` has a typo and `.Query<int>` in conjunction with `x.HasValue` is not legal either.)   And how current is your version of Dapper?

Comment: @KirkWoll just updated Dapper today to make sure it wasn't a version issue.

Comment: I just updated my version of Dapper and I (still) cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KirkWoll I've retried with my example and it does not produce the behavior. I have multiple joins in my actual query and I'm trying reproduce with an example query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem turned out to be that I was doing a `LEFT JOIN` in code, but while I was trying to reproduce the error I was using an `INNER JOIN`, so, I couldn't reproduce the same behavior. With the `LEFT JOIN`, a single row with the value of `NULL` was returned which is why I was getting a casting error between `NULL` and `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `Where` and `Select` don't make any sense if it's an int.  Pretty sure you want to remove them.

```
conn.Query<int>("select 123 where 1=0")
    .ToArray();
```

Do you have any problems when you do that?

Comment: Yes, this is where the problem is. If I make the generic type argument an `int?` instead, I can filter out the ones that don't have a value (which is all of them).

Comment: If the query actual returns values that are `null` then you need to have code looking like your first snippet.  What's wrong with it?  Why change it?

Comment: 0 rows are returned, not a row with `null`. If I change the argument to `int?` I get an `IEnumerable<int?>` with `.Count() == 1` and the `object` is `null`.

Comment: @scottm Then that's a poor decision on behalf of the provider; it really ought to just return an empty enumerable.  Since it's returning an item with null they have given you no choice but to use your first approach.